# Auto Updater Electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

Estou utilizando `Electron` + `VueJS`, e gostaria de saber como implementar o `auto updater`, eu dei uma pesquisada, mas não consegui com nada, para ser honesto, nem entendi como funciona ele, de onde ele baixa a atualização, essas coisas.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo a utilização do `electron-builder` para isso, ele possui uma documentação de publicação e configuração do autoUpdater junto com a build.

Opções de publicação:

- Bintray
- Generic Server
- Github
- Amazon S3
- Digital Ocean Spaces

Auto Update:
https://www.electron.build/auto-update

Publicação:
https://www.electron.build/configuration/publish

Answer (score 0):

Fo implementado em um projeto Angular, porém pode te ajudar.

Utilizei o [electron-winstaller](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer), após o procedimento, é gerado três arquivos:

- projeto-Versão.full.nupkg
- RELEASES
- projetoSetup.exe

O arquivo RELEASES, faz o controle automaticamente das verões a serem atualizadas. Caso atualizar o sistema e realizar o procedimento do winstaller, sera incluído um novo nupkg e adicionado no final arquivo RELEASES.

No main.js inseri o seguinte código:

```
const { autoUpdater } = require('electron');

autoUpdater.on('update-availabe', () => { });
autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => { });
autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', () => { });
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', () => {
  autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
});
autoUpdater.setFeedURL(__IP_DO_SERVIDOR__);
.
.
app.on('ready', () => {
  createBrowserWindow();
  try {
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
  } catch (err) { }
});
```

O servidor, apenas precisa conter os arquivos *.nupkg e RELEASE gerados na build. Eu abri um servidor utilizando o [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). O modulo autoUpdate do electron ao abrir a aplicação, faz as requisições de verificar se há atualização, baixar, instalar e atualizar automaticamente, para isso, o servidor basta estar acessível.

Lembrando que a aplicação deverá ser instalada pelo setup criado pelo electron.